# Compute mean attribute value of point features in same category?

Tags: qgis, point, summarizing

I've got a point shapefile wih a column with categorical variable and a column with numerical values like the one below

```
Point | crop     | NDVI

1     | wheat    | 0.9
2     | barley   | 0.7
3     | wheat    | 0.2 
4     | barley   | 0.5
```

How can I aggregate the points with the same crop showing also the mean NDVI (in a new column) like the result reproduced below in QGIS?

```
Point | crop     | NDVI | meanNDVI

1     | wheat    | 0.9  | 0.55
2     | barley   | 0.7  | 0.6
3     | wheat    | 0.2  | 0.55
4     | barley   | 0.5  | 0.6
```

Comment: Use the `aggregate` functions. https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#aggregates-functions https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/08/aggregate-all-the-things-qgis-expression-edition/

Comment: It was very easy: mean("NDVI", group_by:="crop"). Thank you

Comment: @csk Please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as answered

Comment: @underdark I didn't answer this question, the OP figured it out themselves. And if I post an answer which consists of one sentence and a couple of links, it will be down-voted or possibly deleted as "low quality."

Answer (score 4):

QGIS has a series of [aggregate functions](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#aggregates-functions), including sum, mean, and count.

> Examples:
>
> Return the maximum of the “passengers” field from features in the
>   layer grouped by “station_class” field:
>
> ```
> maximum("passengers", group_by:="station_class")
> ```

So for your case:

```
mean("NDVI", group_by:="crop")
```